# Find similar sites using tag in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

Table `tags`

```
   web          |    tags                                       |     rank

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    google.com   |search,google,searchengine,engine,web          |     1
    facebook.com |facebook,social,networking,friends,community   |     2
    youtube.com  |video,youtube,videos,entertainment,media       |     3
    yahoo.com    |yahoo,search,email,news,searchengine           |     4
    bing.com     |search,searchengine,microsoft,bing,tools       |     25
    twitter.com  |twitter,social,community,blog,socialnetworking |     11
    orkut.com    |orkut,social,google,community,networking       |     109
    myspace.com  |myspace,social,networking,community,friends    |     53
```

Is it possible to find similar sites by searching `web` and order by its `rank` for example

search for `google.com` the result must be `yahoo.com,bing.com` 
(yahoo.com is on 4th rank so bing come after yahoo)

search for `facebook.com` the result must be `myspace.com,orkut.com`(myspace.com is on 53 rank so orkut come after myspace)

OR ELSE

search by `tags` and get above result??

NB

Above one is not a final table structure as this for development...
final structure will be like this

```
web      |     similar
-----------------------
google.com | yahoo.com,bing.com,baidu.com,ask.com
```

etc...

Comment: 1) Fix your database schema so tags are in their own table. 2) If you search for google why don't you get orkut as well? 3) Google is the only one that does web? Huh.

Comment: I want to filter google from result

Answer (score 0):

Search by similarity is particularly complex. However, you can do it with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to execute your requests and [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse response, at this point you can save position of an page on result.

Maybe you want also retrieve the google page rank, you can do it with this class [Google Page Rank Checker](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2682-PHP-Retrieve-the-Google-page-rank-of-a-given-URL.html)

Comment: oops I already have all data with me on tags table...I want find similar sites from tags table only..not talking about parsing